# Django: get many to many objects from multiple objects

Tags: django

```
class Test(models.Model):
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='test_tag')
     ...
```

I have

```
tests = Test.objects.filter(attr='something')
```

Now i want all the tags objects related to tests.

I am trying:

```
Tags.objects.filter('test_tag__in'=tests)
```

but looks its not working

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* use a string literal as key here, this will result in a syntax error, you can write this as:

```
Tag.objects.filter(test_tag__in=tests).distinct()
```

or you can even immediately query on `Tag`s with a related `Test` with `attr=something`, like:

```
Tag.objects.filter(test_tag__attr='something').distinct()
```

The `.distinct()` can be necessary, since we here perform a `JOIN`, and it is possible that the `Tag` object is related to *multiple* `Test` objects in `tests`. By removing the `.distinct()` we thus can obtain the *same* `Tag` multiple times. This is of course not *per se* a problem, but depends on the "context").

Comment: I will check this.